# Eclipse Leshan Server Authentication and Authorization when multiple clients are connected

Tags: eclipse, authentication, authorization, leshan

I am working on Handling security in the Leshan Server when multiple clients are connected. I looked into the source code of the project Leshan. But couldn't figure it out. Could someone please let me know how the leshan server handles security when multiple clients are connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this](https://github.com/eclipse/leshan/tree/master/leshan-server-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/leshan/server/security)

Comment: Thank you. It helped me.

Comment: @Ctienshi No problem. Glad to hear it helped